# How to close PereferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, activity-finish

i'm trying to close the preference activity after i click the back button..but when i press it then click the multi tasking button i see two activities opened for my app the one i'm currently on and the preferenceActvivty which i was on before i pressed back

this is my code

```
public class List extends PreferenceActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SetFrag()).commit();
}

public static class SetFrag extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main);
    }
}
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    List.this.finish ();
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, Usually we need to code before super.onBackPressed() to be called.

So change your code in to this

```
public class List extends PreferenceActivity {
// do some stuff
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
List.this.finish ();
}
```

Edit :

So here is my final answer
paste this custom exit activity in your package

```
public class ExitActivity extends Activity
{
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    {
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }
}

public static void exitApplication(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExitActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

add in manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ExitActivity"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

And call it with

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
ExitActivity.exitApplication(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Good luck

Comment: please check edited answer and tell me review if still not working than tell me

Comment: i can't see how it will make difference..no it doesn't work..i added another piece of code thought it might help

Comment: okay i tried last time hope this time helps you other wise good luck bro :)

Comment: Thanks for your time..i only added the autoRemoveFromRecents im my List activity in manifest file and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!

step 1:In the MainActivity, add flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" to the Intent, then start the SettingsActivity.

step 2: Override the onBuildStartFragmentIntent() method of SettingsActivity(PreferenceActivity) for adding flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT,so that the activityresult can return to the MainActivity.

Like below:
 @Override

```
public Intent onBuildStartFragmentIntent (String fragmentName,
                                       Bundle args,
                                       int titleRes,
                                       int shortTitleRes)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClass(this, getClass());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, fragmentName);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS, args);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_TITLE, titleRes);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT_SHORT_TITLE, shortTitleRes);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NO_HEADERS, true);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);//the new statement
        return intent;
    }
```